# jquery dropdownlist change not working in MVC partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In the main view I have following code

```
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#infopane").attr("src", '@Url.Action("ReportInfo", "Report")');
});
    </script>

<div id="mainSplitter">
    <div style="-ms-overflow-y: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; -ms-overflow-x: hidden;">
        <iframe id="infopane" src="" style="border-bottom: 0px;
            border-left: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="-ms-overflow-y: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; -ms-overflow-x: hidden;">
        <iframe id="searchpane" src="" style="border-bottom: 0px;
            border-left: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Partial view I have following code

```
<div id="Reports">
    <span>Reports:</span> @Html.DropDownList("ddlReports", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Report1", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Report2", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Report3", Value = "3"}
        }, "")
</div>
<div id="ReportInfo">
    @*@{
            Html.RenderPartial("ReportInfo");
        }*@
</div>
```

All I want is to load the second IFRAME(Partial View 2) on change of dropdownlist in the partial view 1.

```
$('#ddlReports').on('change', function () {
                                var val = $(this).val();
                                var x = '@Url.Action("ReportSearch", "Report")' + "/" + val;
                                alert(x);
                                alert($("#searchpane").length);
                                $("#searchpane").attr("src", x);
});
```

I tried adding the dropdownlist jquery change event in Partial view 1 which gets triggered but it does not find the "searchpane" IFRAME.

I also tried adding the dropdownlist jquery change event in the Main view but there its is not triggered at all.

I tried attaching the change event to the dropdown after the Iframe1 loads but still not working.

Can some one please suggest whats the issue here. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why are you using iframes with partialviews? If you  are using partialview you can get rid of the iframe (unless you want or have something special that you need and your are using iframes) but you are telling us you have partial views, get rid of those and load the partialviews with AJAX

Comment: Thanks @JorgeF, already did that over the weekend and it works well now. Replaced IFRAMES with divs and loaded the partialviews using AJAX.